# Linq to Entities or SQL Query Diet

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

Ok, I am fairly new to Linq and I have been looking at the queries in my trace and they are huge.

Lets say I have a table:

```
Id            int PK
name          varchar(50)
AnotherId     int
```

And I want to write this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as RecordCount FROM Names WHERE AnotherId = 1
```

How could I write this in Linq without selecting all the columns from the table?

Basically in trace, I want it to be as simple as the query above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int recordCount = dataContext.Names.Count(i => i.AnotherId == 1);
```

This'll generates a sql query like yours